# How to get specific entry with JS from a DB (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, getjson

I'm trying to do something like a dictionary. The idea is there is a DB online. Someone can search for term and get the description from the db.

How it works:

1) whole terms from the db will be downloaded and compared with searchterm. each term has its specific ID. If the searchterm is the DB the ID will be saved.

2) The ID will be sent to the server with the DB and than it should receive the description

URL to get all Terms

```
http://s288617660.mialojamiento.es/api.php?rquest=terms
```

Url to get description

```
http://s288617660.mialojamiento.es/api.php?rquest=answers&param1=ID
```

Now this is my search function

```
<script>

    getAllTerms();


    function getAllTerms(){
        var url = "http://s288617660.mialojamiento.es/api.php?rquest=terms";

       $.get(url, function(data) {

          localStorage.setItem("terms", JSON.stringify(data));
          //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }).done(function() { /*alert(localStorage.getItem("terms"));*/ })
          .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
          .always(function() { /*alert("finished");*/ });     
    }


    function findTerm(){
        var content = $("#SearchTerm").val();
        //alert(content);
        var id = 0;

        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("terms"));

        $.each(data, function(index, term) {
             //alert("My content " + content + ", term " + term.name);
             if(content == term.name){
                 id = term.id_term;
             }
        });

        //--------------my try to request the description

        var url_answers = "http://s288617660.mialojamiento.es/api.php?rquest=answers&param1="+id;
        //alert(url_answers);
        var answer = "";

        $.get(url_answers, function(data2) {
            localStorage.setItem("answer", JSON.stringify(data2));


            $.each(data2, function(index, object) {

                    answer = object.description+object.id_answer;

            });


        //-----------------end of my try


        //alert(id);
        var htmlStr = "";

        if(parseInt(id) > 0){
            //i found the term
            localStorage.setItem("idterm",id);

            htmlStr = "<li>" + content + "- id: " + id + answer +  "</li>"
        }else{
            //not found 
            htmlStr = "<li>Term not found</li>"
        }

        $('#SearchList').empty();
        $('#SearchList').append(htmlStr);
        $('#SearchList').listview("refresh");

    }


</script>
```

The ID request just works fine but not the description request. Why?
By the way: it's a android phonegap project

Comment: When I try the URL to the description in my browser, it doesn't work. Do you have the right URL?

Comment: you have to replace the ID at the end with any number example: http://s288617660.mialojamiento.es/api.php?rquest=answers&param1=5